# Execute Dynamic Query inside CASE in BigQuery

Tags: sql, loops, google-bigquery

I have a table from where I am fetching the column names and the operations to be performed on the column. This query is executed on another table.

For instance the first table from where I fetch column name and operation:

| Col_name | Operation |
| --- | --- |
| col1 | count |
| col2 | CHAR LENGTH |

The second table on which the operation is to be performed:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| row | sample |
| row2 | sample2 |

The queries should be:

```
select count(col1) from Table2;
select sum(CHAR_LENGTH(col2)) AS from Table2;
```

Initially I thought of using dynamic SQL to pass column name in query inside CASE statement but that is not working. Would appreciate any help.

The case statement logic I tried:

```
Select col1,  CASE WHEN col2 = "CHAR LENGTH" THEN (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE format("""select %s from Table2""", col1))
```

The Execute Immediate command won't work inside CASE statement. I get the error **"Unexpected keyword Immediate"**

Comment: "but that is not working" Can you provide the code you've written that is not working, and describe what is not working about it? Dynamic sql is certainly the way to go here.

Comment: @Error_2646 added the code as an edit

Comment: Have you read the documentation https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#execute_immediate? Usually, and I don't have a BigQuery sandbox to tell for sure on that platform, EXECUTE IMMEDIATE can't be used inside of a query. You need to prepare a query, then EXECUTE IMMEDIATE executes it. What you are doing could kind of work, to build a result of dynamic sql that you could then iterate over to run.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to dynamically generate SQL queries based on the column names and operations specified in the first table. While the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE syntax is not directly applicable in your case, you can achieve dynamic SQL using string concatenation and then executing it.

Here's an example of a dynamic SQL query and execute it:

```
DECLARE
    dynamic_sql VARCHAR(1000);
    result_value NUMBER;
BEGIN
    FOR op_record IN (SELECT Col_name, Operation FROM col1) LOOP
        -- Constructing the dynamic SQL query
        dynamic_sql := 'SELECT ' || op_record.Operation || '(' || op_record.Col_name || ') FROM Table2';

        -- Executing the dynamic SQL query
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE dynamic_sql INTO result_value;

        -- Printing or using the result_value as needed
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Result for ' || dynamic_sql || ': ' || result_value);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Assuming the result is numeric, adjust the datatype as needed.

This PL/SQL block uses dynamic SQL to construct and execute queries based on the column names and operations from the first table (OperationsTable). Adjust the data types and output handling based on your actual requirements.

Keep in mind that using dynamic SQL should be done carefully to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities. Ensure that the input values are properly sanitized before constructing the dynamic SQL queries.

Also, according to @Error_2646, "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE can't be used inside of a query. You need to prepare a query, then EXECUTE IMMEDIATE executes it. What you are doing could kind of work, to build a result of dynamic sql that you could then iterate over to run."

Posting this answer as a Community Wiki since this is the only possible workaround and for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Please feel free to edit this answer for additional information and if there are other possible workarounds/direct solutions for this use case.